# How can I use a comma in a string argument to a rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake, command-line-interface, rakefile

I have the following *Rakefile*:

```
task :test_commas, :arg1 do |t, args|
  puts args[:arg1]
end
```

And want to call it with a single string argument containing commas. Here's what I get:

```
%rake 'test_commas[foo, bar]'
foo

%rake 'test_commas["foo, bar"]'
"foo

%rake "test_commas['foo, bar']"
'foo

%rake "test_commas['foo,bar']"
'foo

%rake "test_commas[foo\,bar]"
foo\
```

I'm currently using the workaround proposed in this [pull request to rake](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/pull/70), but is there a way to accomplish this without patching rake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible. Looking at `lib/rake/application.rb`, the method for parsing the task string is:

```
def parse_task_string(string)
  if string =~ /^([^\[]+)(\[(.*)\])$/
    name = $1
    args = $3.split(/\s*,\s*/)
  else
    name = string
    args = []
  end 
  [name, args]
end
```

It appears that the arguments string is split by commas, so you cannot have an argument that contains a comma, at least not in the current rake-0.9.2.

Comment: This is no longer the case.  Commas can now be escaped with a \

Answer (score 10):

Changing rake is quite a dirty fix. Try using `OptionParser` instead. The syntax is following

```
$ rake mytask -- -s 'some,comma,sepparated,string'
```

the `--` is necessary to skip the rake way of parsing the arguments

and here's the ruby code:

```
task :mytask do
  options = {}

  optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.on('-s', '--string ARG', 'desc of my argument') do |str|
      options[:str] = str
    end

    opts.on('-h', '--help', 'Display this screen') do     
      puts opts                                                          
      exit                                                                      
    end 
  end

  begin 
    optparse.parse!
    mandatory = [:str]
    missing = mandatory.select{ |param| options[param].nil? }
    if not missing.empty?
      puts "Missing options: #{missing.join(', ')}"
      puts optparse
      exit
    end

  rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption, OptionParser::MissingArgument
    puts $!.to_s
    puts optparse
    exit  
  end

  puts "Performing task with options: #{options.inspect}"
  # @TODO add task's code
end
```

Comment: This is a really clean approach from an implementation standpoint. From a usability standpoint, I'm used to using -- to separate options from arguments, especially with git, so it feels weird to have to use -- and then treat the arguments as options. But then again if I cared about usability, I'd probably just go with a custom CLI or use thor :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried escaping the `,` with a `\`?

Comment: yes, and that doesn't work for me either (in any of the cases above). I'll update the question with an example of that.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

[Eugen already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258148/how-can-i-use-a-comma-in-a-string-argument-to-a-rake-task/7259449#7259449), why it doesn't work.

But perhaps the following workaround may help you:

```
task :test_commas, :arg1, :arg2 do |t, args|
  arg = args.to_hash.values.join(',')
  puts "Argument is #{arg.inspect}"
end
```

It takes two arguments, but joins them to get the 'real' one.

If you have more then one comma, you need more arguments.

---

I did some deeper research and found one (or two) solution. 
I don't think it's a perfect solution, but it seems it works.

```
require 'rake'
module Rake
  class Application
    #usage: 
    #   rake test_commas[1\,2\,3]
    def parse_task_string_masked_commas(string)
      if string =~ /^([^\[]+)(\[(.*)\])$/
        name = $1
        args = $3.split(/\s*(?<!\\),\s*/).map{|x|x.gsub(/\\,/,',')}
      else
        name = string
        args = []
      end 
      [name, args]
    end   

    #Usage: 
    #   rake test_commas[\"1,2\",3]
    #" and ' must be masked
    def parse_task_string_combined(string)
      if string =~ /^([^\[]+)(\[(.*)\])$/
        name = $1
        args = $3.split(/(['"].+?["'])?,(["'].+?["'])?/).map{|ts| ts.gsub(/\A["']|["']\Z/,'') }
        args.shift if args.first.empty?
      else
        name = string
        args = []
      end 
      [name, args]
    end   

    #~ alias :parse_task_string :parse_task_string_masked_commas
    alias :parse_task_string :parse_task_string_combined

  end

end
desc 'Test comma separated arguments'
task :test_commas, :arg1  do |t, args|
  puts '---'
  puts "Argument is #{args.inspect}"
end
```

The version `parse_task_string_masked_commas`allows calls with masked commas:

```
rake test_commas[1\,2\,3]
```

The version `parse_task_string_combined` allows:

```
rake test_commas[\"1,2,3\"]
```

At least under windows, the " (or ') must be masked. If not, they are already deleted until the string reached Rake::Aplication (probably shell substitution)

Comment: That's a good workaround if I know the input format beforehand, but in that case I could just name the arguments so `rake -T` would be more descriptive.

Comment: I added a new version - it's a bit nearer your proposals.

Comment: This would be worth submitting as an upstream patch, so that you can include commas in strings. What about using a regex with negative lookbehind (matching a comma that isn't preceded by a slash) instead of using MYSEP?

Comment: I made some experiments with regexps, but I didn't have success. Then I was too tired to continue...  I will take a 2nd look for it.

Comment: I replaced MYSEP at least for the maked comma version. For parameters in " I have actual no better idea.

Comment: I have now a solution without the MYSEP-replacements.

Comment: I like the version with escaping the quotes the best, although it's still not ideal, as escaping quotes usually means I want a literal quote, where here it's just a workaround to get the quotes far enough into the parsing so we can deal with them. When I try running this (on osx) using ruby-1.9.2-p290 I can't get it to output commas in the string. The output is `Argument is {:arg1=>"1"}` even when I escape the quotes.

Comment: Use `args.to_a` instead of `args.to_hash.values`. Hash data structures don't preserve order.

Answer (score 3):

Rake task variables are not very convenient generally, instead use environment variables:

```rb
task :my_task do
  ENV["MY_ARGUMENT"].split(",").each_with_index do |arg, i|
    puts "Argument #{i}: #{arg}"
  end
end
```

Then you can invoke with

```
MY_ARGUMENT=foo,bar rake my_task
```

Or if you prefer

```
rake my_task MY_ARGUMENT=foo,bar
```

Comment: Thanks! All the options presented here are a bit dirty and/or ugly, but this was by far the quickest.

Answer (score 3):

For rake version 12.3.2,

> rake test_commas["foo\,bar"]

works well

Answer (score 2):

Another simple workaround is to use a different delimiter in your arguments.

It's pretty simple to swap to a pipe | character (or another) instead of your comma separated args.  Rake parses your arguments correctly in this case and allows you to split the first for an array.

```
desc 'Test pipe separated arguments'
task :test_pipes, :arg1, :arg2  do |t, args|
  puts ":arg1 is: #{ args[:arg1] }"
  puts ":arg2 still works: #{ args[:arg2] }"
  puts "Split :arg1 is: #{ args[:arg1].split('|') }"
end
```

Call it with:

```
rake test_pipes["foo|bar",baz]
```

Answer (score 2):

`# rake -v 10.5`

`rake test_commas\['foo\,bar'\]`

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert each string to symbol, 
As,

```
task :create do   
ARGV.each { |a| task a.to_sym do ; end }
 puts ARGV[1]
 puts ARGV[2]
 puts ARGV[3]
 puts ARGV[4]     
end
end
```

run as,

rake create '1,s' '2' 'ww ww' 'w,w'